# Manga/manhwa about a female reincarnated as a noble who gets kidnapped as a baby

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The main character is reincarnated into a fantasy world as the child of a noble family. I can’t remember how old she is when she is kidnapped, but two or younger I think. Her father interrupts mid-kidnapping and chases them but the kidnappers escape outside of some barrier surrounding the territory that he can’t leave so he loses them.

He goes home to his wife distraught that he couldn’t protect her.  Outside the barrier are these specter creatures that are the spirits of the dead and if they touch you, you die. The kidnappers get killed and she is taken in by some mercenary group. They know she is some noble child because of her unique eyes and she tells them her name but for some reason can’t get her home yet.

They take her in and there is another bit with unique eyes in the group. There are magic stones and she is able to use or charge them and create a barrier to block the specters. I think it was colored but not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I don’t remember when. A few years ago and it was ongoing which is why I stopped. It was still fairly new then with not many chapters out. I wanna say I read it on mangago since that is my usual site but again. Can’t remember for sure

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Tensei Youjo wa Akiramenai](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tensei-youjo-wa-akiramenai)*.

> When I woke up, I had been **reborn as a baby**. My mother passed away and I was neglected by my father. Even though I was born in a Marquis family, my life started on a HARD MODE. But I won’t be discouraged. I will eat well, sleep well, move much, get whatever I can get and live happily. This is a story of a little girl **with the power to create barriers** involving everybody to become happy.

In the first few chapters the protagonist is kidnapped as a baby. One of the household maids is blackmailed into kidnapping her, due to the maid's brother's illness and the cost of medicine.

[image: Kidnapping]

The family doesn't quite interrupt mid-kidnapping. It's a multi-day (and multi-chapter) event. The maid slips off with the protagonist in the middle of the night, and her family pursues the kidnappers, but only after several days of searching.

Barriers and hollows are also explicitly mentioned.

[image: Barrier]

Comment: @Sara You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).